# cordova build errord gradle

Tags: eclipse, cordova, gradle, proxy

i'm trying to install cordova and open a project on eclipse...this error is coming out when typing **cordova build android** i setted the proxy gradle.properties under project_folder\prova\platforms\android also under all gradle directory...

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0+.
     Required by:
         :android:unspecified
      > Failed to list versions for com.android.tools.build:gradle.
         > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/co
m/android/tools/build/gradle/maven-metadata.xml.
            > Could not GET 'https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/bu
ild/gradle/maven-metadata.xml'.
               > Connection reset by peer: connect

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug
option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 25.641 secs
Built the following apk(s):
```

proxy settings:

```
systemProp.http.proxyHost=***
systemProp.http.proxyPort=3128
systemProp.http.proxyUser=***
systemProp.http.proxyPassword=***
systemProp.http.nonProxyHosts=*.nonproxyrepos.com|localhost  

systemProp.https.proxyHost=***
systemProp.https.proxyPort=***
systemProp.https.proxyUser=***
systemProp.https.proxyPassword=***
systemProp.https.nonProxyHosts=*.nonproxyrepos.com|localhost
```

i've already read other post so i've already tryied different procedure...

Comment: With the Android SDK manager maybe also install the `Android Support Repository` under `Extra`

Comment: previously done...not working...

Comment: Lorenzo - did you ever find a solution to this? I'm having the exact same problem.

Comment: yes, using my phone as a router :D